# The Theory of Object oriented programming

Tags: oop, inheritance, logic, hierarchy

This question concerns a generalized approach to building up a hierarchy of objects. I shall use an example to explain my questions.

Suppose im building a digital circuit simulator, and we do this with an Object-oriented class structure. The base class is logic gates, from which we derive binary gates and unary gates, then from binary gates, we derive the classes AND, OR, XOR etc. and from unary gates, we derive the class for a NOT gate. This makes sense, as at each layer you become more specified, and you branch into subsets which have data that is unique to that derived class.

But suppose then we want to build something out of our derived logic gate classes, for example, an 8-bit adder circuit. In this case, the 8-bit adder is not part of the original hierarchy structure - it is not a logic gate, but despite that, it can be built of out of the logic gate objects. Additionally, the 8-bit adder can be broken down into 8 full adders, which can each be broken down into 2 half adders. But as opposed to the original logic gate hierarchy, each of these objects (8-bit adder, full adder & half adder) all operate as individual components, whereas the only classes which actually serve as a component from the logic gate hierarchy are the final derived classes, AND, OR, XOR, NOT. In this sense, I don't understand whether or not it would be appropriate to create a class structure based on inheritance for the adder circuits.

To me, it seems as though the half-adder, full-adder and 8-bit adder, should each be comprised of individual logic gate objects, but this would be inefficient as it would require lots of repetition of code, and so this begs the question, what is the best way to arrange these class structures so that the most complex 8-bit adder can be built from full adders, and the full adders can be built from half adders, and the half adders can be built from individual logic gates.

Many thanks to all that answer.

Comment: This is a very broad and subjective question getting an objective answer will be difficult. Since you tagged it [tag:c++] I assume you are looking for c++ specific solutions?

Comment: *"the 8-bit adder is not part of the original hierarchy structure - it is not a logic gate, but despite that, it can be built of out of the logic gate objects"* - research **composition**.

Comment: not everything can be (and should not be) modeled as inheritance structure, sometimes composition is better (and often is much better), also you can just have independent objects which conform to some interface(s)

Comment: I would say the answer depends on what functionality you need from your adder objects. Would they have member functions, and if so would 8-bit adders, full adders, and half adders have the same functions?

Comment: It may be helpful to you to read up on the **Liskov Substitution Principle**.

Comment: @Timo Well C++ is my language of choice, so that would be appreciated, but of course If someone can explain the theory which I can then implement myself, that would be perfect. Less so looking for code snippets, more so looking for ideas.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'll look into that thanks.

Comment: @IłyaBursov seems like I need to wrap my head around that

Comment: @MilesTurin This is actually part of the problem. All my binary logic gates for example take in two boolean inputs, so they can all be derived from the same class. However with regards to the adders, the full adder takes in 3 boolean inputs ( bit A, bit B and a carry bit) , whereas the 8-bit adder should take in 3 inputs, but this time those inputs are two 8 bit integers (to be operated on) and a control signal which decides if the operation is addition or subtractions. For reference im basing the 8-bit adder on [this design] (https://imgur.com/Vj8OpF7).

Comment: @user4581301 I'll look into it, thanks